# p-dropdown doesn't show value from form

Tags: angular, forms, dropdown, primeng

I'm getting a problem when I use the p-dropdown component binding a form. I have a Form Group with Form Controls that have our own values pre-loaded and the value of one of this controls should be showed at p-dropdown component. But it isn't visible when the page load.

I use the Dropdown look like:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="vehicleTypes" placeholder="Vehicle Type" optionLabel="label" formControlName="vehicleType">
```

And my component have a Form Group that have a Form Control named vehicleType and with the value.

```
{label: "TYPE 1", value: "1"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you having label in formcontrol? Just keep value in formControl like this:

app.component.ts

```
appForm: FormGroup;

vehicles = [
 {value: 1, label: 'v1'},
 {value: 2, label: 'v2'},
 {value: 3, label: 'v3'},
 {value: 4, label: 'v4'},
 {value: 5, label: 'v5'},
 {value: 6, label: 'v6'},
]

constructor(
 private fb: FormBuilder
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.appForm = this.fb.group({
  vehicleType: new FormControl(2)
});
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="appForm">
 <p-dropdown [optionLabel]="label" placeholder="Vehicle Type" 
  [options]="vehicles" formControlName="vehicleType"></p-dropdown>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The dropdown keep showing place holder.

Comment: I added code on stackblitz for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkw4rd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

The values have to be set to your `vehicleTypes` like:

```
vehicleTypes = [
    {label: "TYPE 1", value: "1"}
]
```

and `vehicleType` is a FormControl like Bravin said.

Generally, we could use first element as a placeholder.